# Qt and Boost circular buffer

Tags: qt, boost, cmake, circular-buffer

I'm trying to include the boost circular buffer into my project.  I installed boost onto my computer using macports.  not sure what library to include for the boost libs but I have included the headers files. Below is my cmake files.

```
QT       += core gui

TARGET = DVD
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += /opt/local/include/boost

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    worker.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    worker.h
```

Comment: is the circular buffer included in a certain boost lib *.a file or is all the coded included in the header file?  right now I am getting errors saying it can't find the file

Comment: According to http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries, circular buffers is not header only.

Comment: Sorry. Libraries listed here are the one that are *not* header only!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `boost` from `INCLUDEPATH += /opt/local/include/boost` because, in the source file, you will be including boost libraries like in your case "boost/circular_buffer.hpp".

I think the compiler is complaining because there is no `boost` folder under `/opt/local/include/boost`.

Comment: Yea that was my problem.  Thank you very much.